# ASP.NET Site slow until recycle

Tags: asp.net

I just recently move a site from IIS6 to IIS7 and are experiencing a lot of performance problems.

The site performance is really bad until I do a recycle on the Application Pool. What can this be a symptom of?

I recycle ever night but that seems not to be enough?

I'm not relying that much on Sessions. Use caching quite a lot.

Comment: you probably have forgotten open handles, or other memory issues, maybe the computer runs out of physical memory... if do have direct access to the computer you can check some thinks.

Comment: I have full access to the computer. Please advice what to check?

Comment: use the Process Explorer from sysinternals and check the physical memory.

Comment: This could be a generic type of answer but I really doubt it. You should list your code here as it sounds like its your systematic approach to handing caching and sessions. I have over 50 ecommerce sites with high traffic using a light-weight approach to caching and serialization that scale very well. You would have to list your code out so we can see what you are doing to cause this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find some very good tutorials on how to debug the most common types of hang, performance, memory and crash scenarios with .NET and ASP.NET here: [.NET Debugging Demos - Information and setup instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx). These series are really worth reading, as it's full of information, but it takes quite a time :-)

One common problem for server-side apps is to allocate tons of "big" .NET objects that hit the [Large Object Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx). Check out if you do a lot of `byte[]` or `MemoryStream` allocations bigger than 85Kb (objects with a contiguous size higher than this will go in the LOH and this heap cannot be compacted) for example. This tipically happens if you do a lot of big file (PDF, images, etc.) generation, copying, etc... This should be done using pure streaming without full size allocations.

Answer (score 3):

After releasing some new .NET components in my web sites, I'm experiencing app pool memory consuming too.
I'm recycling the memory manually (about once a day), but I'm going to implement a job that recycles the memory with a treshold.

Any way, look for clean up statements, connections closing, objects destruction, etc.